# Rails: devise route generating an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes

I am using devise in my application.

Form routes.rb:

```
  devise_for :users

  authenticated :user do
    root :to => 'pages#home'
  end

  root :to => 'pages#home'

  match '/about', to: "pages#about"
  match '/request_invite', to: "users#sign_up"
```

From my _headers.html.erb

```
<li><%= link_to HOME_TITLE,    root_path  %></li>
<li><%= link_to REQUEST_INVITE_TITLE,    request_invite_path  %></li>
<li><%= link_to ABOUT_TITLE,    about_path %></li>
```

When I check my routes (rake routes), I have the following:

```
request_invite        /request_invite(.:format)      users#sign_up
```

When I do:

```
http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up
```

I do see the invite form.

If I click on the Request Invite link in the header, I get the following error:

> uninitialized constant UsersController

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Correct this in  route file

```
   match '/request_invite', to: "users/registration#new"
```

Hope work for you

Comment: I tried it and I'm getting the following error message: uninitialized constant Users

Comment: here's what ended up working:

    devise_for :users, :path => '', :path_names => { :sign_in => "login", :sign_out => "logout", :sign_up => "request_invite" }

and delete

    match '/request_invite', to: "users#sign_up"